# How to disable CSS minifier in Liferay?

Tags: css, liferay

I am using Liferay 5.2.3 CE. 
How can I disable css minifier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do this for the whole Liferay instance by specifying

```
theme.css.fast.load=false
```

in your portal-ext.properties file. However, if it's for verification pupose, you can just add css_fast_load=0 in your request parameters.

Arnaud